# Enabling Google Rich Snippets for products

Tags: schema.org, microdata, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets

I have added product rich snippets on my webpage. After some time I can see on Google Webmaster Tools page that Google crawled my website and found structured data. I also tested my product page by [testing tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) and it says **All Good**. But I can't see the result when searching page. Google still displays like regular page and not with appropriate items.

Items which I have put are:

- Name
- Image
- Description
- Price
- PriceCurrency
- Availability

Here is the my HTML:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">

  <h3 itemprop="name">Product Name</h3>
  <img itemprop="image" src="image_url" />
  <div itemprop="description">
    <p>Product Description</p>
  </div>
  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
      <p><strong>Price: </strong>
        <span itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD">$</span>
        <span itemprop="price" content="125">125</span>
        <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock"/>                                                 
      </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Is there something else to keep in mind when enabling Rich Snippets?

Comment: The markup you have included doesn’t show a `Product` item. I assume you have provided it on your page but didn’t include it here?

Comment: Yes, I forget to include it here. I have wrapped that code with the div - <div class="row" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">.  Here is example page: http://marketgeo.ge/ge/products/product/206/